# Structure blog posts by using post ids as id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How do I structure blog posts/comments in HTML so that I can select them later on using jQuery/Javascript for updating/deleting/Ajax calls?

My instinct is to use those posts'/comments' IDs (primary key in the database) as their `id=` attributes in HTML e.g.

```
<section class="posts">
  <div id=**post's ID (primary key) here**> post </div>
</section>
```

Is this a bad thing? (exposing details to the web such as primary keys, etc) or not necessarily?

Comment: It's fine to expose your primary keys, so long as they are only used to uniquely identify the records and don't contain any sensitive information (security tokens, personal details etc).

Comment: @dan How about user `id`s to be used e.g. in a friends/users list? Are user ids a little bit sensitive or just fine as with other resources like posts/comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that. Assuming your server returns a list of entities in JSON:

```
{
    "comments": [
        { "id": "001", "author": "Jack", "comment": "Hello" },
        { "id": "002", "author": "Jill", "comment": "there" }
    ],
    "posts": [
        { "id": "003", "author": "Greg", "comment": "This is an awesome website." },
    ]
}
```

You could use the id property of each to store it in the HTML for later retrieval:

```
<div id='001'>Hello</div>
<div id='002'>there</div>
```

Remember HTML `id`s are global across the entire page, so your `id`s across comments, posts, and any other entities present on the page must be unique. It might be a good idea to prefix them to avoid collisions, like `comment001`, `comment002`, `post001`, etc.

This is essentially what other frameworks do (like React) behind the scenes.

Comment: Got it. If this is how React is doing it then that means I am good to go. Thought about prefixing as well as id collisions will happen if it's just the `id`s. Thanks!